# Can a closed disc in the plane be partitioned into three disjoint sets which are pair-wise isometric?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, isometries

Any progress on the following: Can a closed disc in the plane be partitioned into three disjoint sets which are pair-wise isometric, i.e. each set is an image of the others under an isometry?

Comment: Is it a well known problem? Any references?

Comment: This is probably stupid, but why not cutting the cake in three equal parts (taking only half of the boundary)?

Comment: @Oblomov: center point?

Comment: Why specifically three?  Do you know the answer for some specific $n>1$?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I would guess that the question is about $n=3$ since this is the least nontrivial case. For $n=2$ both parts must have the same diameter as the disc so that you obtain a collision at the center.

Comment: @AdamPrzeździecki: I must be tired, I still can't see the argument for $n=2$, could you spell it out in more detail? (Perhaps adding it to the question itself.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen OK, suppose the disc $D$ is divided into two disjoint isometric subsets of strictly smaller diameter, say $A$ and $B$. Then for every diagonal of $D$ one of its ends belongs to $A$ while the other to $B$. But since the circle is connected we must have a point on the boundary that belongs to the closure of $A$ and of $B$, the other end of the corresponding diagonal belongs neither to $A$ nor to $B$. A contradiction. Now let the center $c$ of $D$ belong to say $A$. Let $a,b\in\bar A$ be the ends of some diagonal of $D$. Then any isometry that keeps $A$ inside of $D$ must preserve $c$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen write the disc as $A\cup B$. First observe that neither $A$ nor $B$ can contain the unit circle. Second, take a point $x$ in the unit circle at the boundary of $A$ (so $x$ is in the closure of both $A$ and $B$). Then $-x$ is either in $A$ or $B$, so either $A$ or $B$ has diameter 2. Since they are isometric, both have diameter 2. Isometries not fixing the center cannot move a subset of diameter 2 inside the disc. Hence the isometry mapping $A$ to $B$ fixes 0, and thus we get a problem at 0.

Comment: Actually there is no convex compact set which is a disjoint union of two isometric parts (I know this for a while but forgot from where.)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the first place I would look for it is Hadwiger, DeBrunner, and Klee, Combinatorial Geometry in the Plane, now available in a Dover paperback edition. Or possibly Gelbaum & Olmsted, Counterexamples in Analysis.